# Como retornar um parâmetro "OUT" em SmartDevices Genexus Ev3 U1?

Tags: android, genexus, return

Desenvolvo com Genexus Smart Devices Ev3 U1 para Android.

Pretendo desenvolver uma tela **Pai** que ao clicar num botão abre a tela **Filho**, onde o usuário seleciona um item num grid e volta para o Pai exibindo o item clicado.

**Porém não retorna o parâmetro "out" do Filho.**

### Veja como estou tentando:

no Panel "**Pai**" há um botão com o evento abaixo:

```
Event 'Adicionar Lugar'
Composite
pnPromptCota.Call(&addLugVCOTA_COTACODIGO)
TextblockLugarDs.Caption = &addLugVCOTA_COTACODIGO.ToString()
Interop.Msg('&addLugVCOTA_COTACODIGO= '+&addLugVCOTA_COTACODIGO.ToString().Trim())
EndComposite
Endevent
```

---

No Panel "**Filho**" (o Prompt de seleção) tem uma grid com evento Tap:

```
parm(
    out: &VCOTA_COTACODIGO
    );


Event VCOTA_COTACODIGO.Tap
&VCOTA_COTACODIGO = VCOTA_COTACODIGO
SDActions.Return()
Endevent
```

---

Porém quando **retorna traz código zero** (em "Interop.Msg....").

Para mim não tem lógica, parece tudo certo, tal como eu faria na programação Web com Genexus.

O que posso mudar para fazer o OUT retornar?

Aguardo retorno. Obrigado!

Obs: Já tentei só o "return" ao invés do "SDActions.Return()" e não funciona também.

Answer (score 1):

Em algum aplicativo eu fiz algo parecido com o que você menciona. Foi baseado em este [exemplo](http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/hwikibypageid?21618).
Pelo que eu vi no seu caso a diferença mais importante é que você usa o evento "tap" (Event VCOTA_COTACODIGO.Tap) e no exemplo (e no meu caso) foi configurado como "default action" do "grid". De repente, você pode tentar implementá-lo como está no exemplo.